# Windows 10 Adaptive Tiles do not work when built with .NET native toolchain

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am out of ideas here. This is a Windows 10 Universal App. I am currently trying to get the Adaptive Tiles working with the Compile .NET Native Toolchain on. They work perfectly with the option off. Running on Visual Studio 2015(have also tried 2017 with the same results).

```
TileContent tContent = new TileContent();
TileVisual tVisual = new TileVisual();
TileBinding tTileSmall = new TileBinding();
TileBindingContentAdaptive tTileContent = new TileBindingContentAdaptive();
AdaptiveText tChildren = new AdaptiveText();

tChildren.Text = "Small";
tTileContent.Children.Add(tChildren);

tTileSmall.Content = tTileContent;
tVisual.DisplayName = "El Dudenheimer";
tVisual.TileSmall = tTileSmall;
tVisual.TileMedium = tTileSmall;
tVisual.TileLarge = tTileSmall;
tVisual.TileWide = tTileSmall;
tContent.Visual = tVisual;

string contentString = string.Empty;
foreach(var node in tContent.GetXml().ChildNodes)
{ contentString += node.GetXml(); }


var notification = new TileNotification(tContent.GetXml());

TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication().Update(notification);

contentString with .NET Toolchain on - <?xml version="1.0"?><tile><visual/></tile>

contentString with .NET Toolchain off - <?xml version="1.0"?><tile><visual displayName="El Dudenheimer"><binding template="TileSmall"><text>Small</text></binding><binding template="TileMedium"><text>Small</text></binding><binding template="TileWide"><text>Small</text></binding><binding template="TileLarge"><text>Small</text></binding></visual></tile>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue with your code snippet, it can work well on my side. I target the uwp app as build 14393 since you are using VS2015. Did you get some exceptions when .NET native toolchain checked? Or didn't you get the expect result?

Comment: I was missing the Scale-200 assets. Works goodly now.

Comment: Turns out that after doing a bunch of things I added the Scale-200 Assets. That is not what made it work. In the default.rd.xml file the line

Comment: <Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />

Comment: was     <Assembly Name="MyApp" Dynamic="Required All" />

Comment: Apparently you need to use *Application* and not your application name

Comment: There are Asterix before and after Application